# Adapting text to width of container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to adapt a few `a` elements to the total width of the container they are in.

This is the code that I currently have: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FsgvI

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">
    <div class="something">
      <h3>
        <a href="#">This is foo</a>
        >
        <a href="#">and then bar</a>
        >
        <a href="#">and then test</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    asdijfg asoidf oasidf aosidf
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
}

.title {
  height: 30px;
}

h3, h3 > a {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

How can I make the text adapt to the width of the `box` container? And by "adapt" I mean keep the current font size and cut (ellipsis) the text that doesn't fit inside.

Regards

Edit:

Sorry for the missunderstanding. I can't set a width to the `box` class because I don't know how wide it will be. I need it to be as wide as many items (`content` box) as there are.

Comment: You need to specify a width to `.box` class or it will get the same width as your <a> tags.

Comment: @caeth but that's the whole point! I can't do that because I don't know how wide box would get, it could be 100px or it could be 500px.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgGuA You'll need to set some sort of width otherwise how is it to know when to cut the text and show the ellipsis? Perhaps you could use `max-width` instead?

Comment: No, sorry, I can't set width to `box` class. Please see my update @HiddenHobbes

Comment: @alexandernst Thanks for the clarification, I think I've achieved what you are after in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with a few changes to your CSS.

- Make `.title` `position: relative;` this will make `h3` position relative to it
- Make `h3` `position: absolute;` to take it out of the document flow and give it `width: 100%`
- Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `h3` stop the contents wrapping onto the new line
- Remove `width: 170px;` from `.content` to allow it to take up as much space as it needs

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">
    <div class="something">
      <h3>
        <a href="#">This is foo</a>
        >
        <a href="#">and then bar</a>
        >
        <a href="#">and then test</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    asdijfg asoidf oasidf aosidf
  </div>
</div>
```

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgkJr

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a width to the containing element and add the `white-space: nowrap;` to the .something div.

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  width:170px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
}

.title {
  height: 30px;
}
.something{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: No, sorry, I can't set width to `box` class. Please see my update

Comment: Can the title be contained in the content div like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/msofE?